# I need some help converting the following code from C++ to C

Tags: c++, c, url-rewriting, converters

I am having trouble converting code from c++ to c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for starters; you can get rid of `<iostream>` and `<fstream>` includes. Replace them with `<stdio.h>`.

You don't need namespace std if I'm not mistaken also.

Replace strings with char*.
Replace `cout` with `printf`.

For opening/reading files you can use `fopen`. Example:

```
FILE *ifp, *ofp;
char *mode = "r";
char outputFilename[] = "out.list";

ifp = fopen("in.list", mode);

if (ifp == NULL) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Can't open input file in.list!\n");
  exit(1);
}

ofp = fopen(outputFilename, "w");

if (ofp == NULL) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Can't open output file %s!\n",
          outputFilename);
  exit(1);
}
```

For further input/output information please look [here](http://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/c/file-io/intro/).

Comment: I have updated my code above, if you could help me a bit further, I would appreciate it!

Comment: @user3453745: No you didn´t. Get rid of ALL things with streams (like the ifstream parameter of checkit), all things with namespace, "string"s etc. too. Additionally, get rid of `system("pause")` too. And there is no `NULL()`. Then look up ho to use char-arrays, and scanf

Comment: Yes okay that works. How would I convert the ifstream parameter of checkit? Thank you!

Comment: Right, I really am not sure what you're talking about

Answer (score 0):

We use FILE in C instead of fstream.

```
FILE *fp=fopen("test.txt","r+")
if(!fp)

printf("can't open file\n");

while(!feof(fp))
{
i=0;
fscanf(fp,"%lf",&data);
printf("%lf",data);
}
```

If you want use String in C.You have to use Char[].

```
char *test = "abcd";
char  test2[10] = "abcd";
```

Comment: I have updated my code above, if you could help me a bit further, I would appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

In C, you can only use `char *` or `char []` for string.
`fstream` is implements high-level input/output operations on file based streams for C++. In C, use `FILE` struct and `fopen/fclose` to open/close file. fgetc/fputc to read/write file.

Comment: I have updated my code above, if you could help me a bit further, I would appreciate it!